# Ray tracer not giving different light intensities based on direction

Tags: c, graphics, geometry, raytracing

**Goal:** I am trying to create a ray tracer in C. I just added in a light source that should give each of my three spheres a shading effect based on where the light is. If the light is to the left of all of them, a shadow should be cased on the right.

**Problem:** When changing the light intensities and position of the light, all the spheres are changed uniformly. The spheres will be more or less lit equally and there is no variation of lighting on individual pixels on the sphere.

**My debugging attempts:** I have tried looking through the variable outputs by printing out a lot of different info and I think the source comes from my variable

```
diffuse_light_intensity
```

which does not change much (through all the iterations on the screen the value changes twice when it should be changing quite often due to the angles of the light on the surface changing quite a bit)

**My Code: (my theory is the problem lies in scene_intersect() or cast_ray())**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
    float position[3];
    float intensity;
} Light;

typedef struct {
    float diffuse_color[3];

}  Material;

typedef struct {
    float center[3];
    float radius;
    Material material;

} Sphere;

int arrSub(const float arr1[], const float arr2[], float subArr[], int length) {
    /*
    Requires 3 equally sized arrays (denoted as length),
    arr1 - arr2 will result in the third array subArr
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        subArr[i] = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int arrAdd(const float arr1[], const float arr2[], float addArr[], int length) {
    /*
    Requires 3 equally sized arrays (denoted as length),
    arr1 + arr2 will result in the third array subArr
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        addArr[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int arrScalarMult(const float arr1[], float scalar, float newArr[], int length) {
    /*
    Requires 3 equally sized arrays (denoted as length),
    arr1 - arr2 will result in the third array subArr
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr1[i] * scalar;
    }
    return 0;
}

float dotProduct(const float arr1[], const float arr2[], int length) {
    /*
    Returns the dot product of two equal sized arrays 
    (treated as vectors)

    a (dot) b = a1b1 + a2b2 + ... anbn
    */
    float result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int normalize(float arr[], int len) {
    //Normalize a vector (array)

    float sumSqr;
    float norm;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sumSqr += arr[i] * arr[i];
    }

    norm = sqrt(sumSqr);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] / norm;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool ray_intersect(const float origin[], const float dir[], float t0, Sphere s) {
    /*
    Ray-Sphere Intersection

    Vectors:
        origin (the zero vector)
        dir (direction vector)
        L (vector from origin to center of sphere)
    Scalars:
        tca
        d2
        thc
        t0
        t1    
    */
    float L[3] = {0,0,0}; //The zero vector
    arrSub(s.center, origin, L, 3); //L is now the vector from origin to the sphere's center

    float tca = dotProduct(L, dir, 3); //Projection of L onto dir
    float d2 = dotProduct(L, L, 3) - tca*tca;

    if (d2 > s.radius * s.radius) return false; //There is no intersection, so return false.

    float thc = sqrtf((s.radius*s.radius - d2));
    t0 = tca - thc;
    float t1 = tca + thc;
    if (t0 < 0) {
        t0 = t1;
    }
    if (t0 < 0) return false;

    return true;
}

bool scene_intersect(const float origin[], const float dir[], const Sphere s[], int len, float hit[], float N[], Material * ptr_m) {
    float sphere_dist = INT_MAX;

    for (size_t i=0; i < len; i++) {
        float dist_i;
        if (ray_intersect(origin, dir, dist_i, s[i]) && dist_i < sphere_dist) {
            sphere_dist = dist_i;

            float dirDist[3];
            arrScalarMult(dir, dist_i, dirDist, 3);
            arrAdd(origin, dirDist, hit, 3);

            float hitMinusCenter[3];
            arrSub(hit, s[i].center, hitMinusCenter, 3);
            normalize(hitMinusCenter, 3);

            N[0] = hitMinusCenter[0];
            N[1] = hitMinusCenter[1];
            N[2] = hitMinusCenter[2];

            * ptr_m = s[i].material;
        }
    }
    return sphere_dist<1000;
}

int cast_ray(const float origin[], const float dir[], const Sphere s[], const Light l[], int l_size, unsigned char colorArr[]) {
    float point[3], N[3];
    Material m;
    Material * ptr_m = &m;

    if (!scene_intersect(origin, dir, s, 3, point, N, ptr_m)) {
        //background
        colorArr[0] = 5; //red
        colorArr[1] = 100; //green
        colorArr[2] = 250; //blue
    } else {
        float diffuse_light_intensity = 0;
        float light_dir[3];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < l_size; i++) {
            arrSub(l[i].position, point, light_dir, 3);
            normalize(light_dir, 3);
            diffuse_light_intensity += l[i].intensity * ((0.f >= dotProduct(light_dir, N, 3) ? (0.f) : (dotProduct(light_dir, N, 3))));
        }
        //light up pixel
        colorArr[0] = m.diffuse_color[0] * diffuse_light_intensity;
        colorArr[1] = m.diffuse_color[1] * diffuse_light_intensity;
        colorArr[2] = m.diffuse_color[2] * diffuse_light_intensity;
    }

    return 0;
}

int render(const Sphere s[], const Light l[], int l_length) {
    /*
    Creates image in a new color each step.
    */
    const int width = 1024;
    const int height = 768;

    FILE *fp = fopen("fourth.ppm", "wb"); // Write in binary mode
    (void) fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

    float fov = 3.1415926535/2.; // Field of View

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            float x = (2*(i+.5)/(float)width - 1)*tan(fov/2.)*width/(float)height;
            float y = -(2*(j+.5)/(float)height - 1)*tan(fov/2.);

            float dir[] = {x,y,-1};
            normalize(dir, 3);

            unsigned char color[3];
            const float origin[] = {0,0,0};
            cast_ray(origin, dir, s, l, l_length, color);
            (void) fwrite(color, 1, 3, fp);
        }
    }
    (void) fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    Material red = {255,0,0};
    Material pink = {150,10,150};
    Material gold = {255, 195, 0};

    //Populate with spheres
    Sphere s[3];
    Sphere originalS = {{-3,0,-16},2,gold};
    Sphere bigS = {{-1.0, -1.5, -12}, 3, red};
    Sphere anotherS = {{7,5,-18},2,pink};

    s[0] = originalS;
    s[1] = bigS;
    s[2] = anotherS;

    //Add light source
    Light l[1];

    Light test_light = {{-20,20,20}, 1.5};

    l[0] = test_light;

    render(s,l, 1);
    printf("Run success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If any clarification is needed on my code please let me know, I am quite new to both C and stackoverflow.

Comment: I just get a blue background - no balls at all.

Comment: @Alnitak That's strange. Is the compiler giving you no errors or warnings? It should create 3 balls on the screen.

Comment: ok, it "works" if I disable optimisation.

Comment: @Alnitak I have no idea why it would have that effect. If you don't see balls then it must be caused by !scene_intersect() always returning true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fundamental error in `ray_intersect` where you're passing the `t0` variable by value, and not as a pointer, and therefore in the `scene_intersect` function its value is always zero.

The other problem is that you don't initialize the `sumSqr` in the `normalize` function, resulting in that function returning `NaN` for each vector component.

With those two fixed I get something approximating shaded balls.  The errors in that image are caused by failing to ensure that your output pixel values fall in the range [0, 255].

NB: *both* of these first errors are detected if you turn on full compiler error checking, warning you of uninitialised variables being used.

Comment: This fixes my shading problem, thank you. How do you enable full compiler error checking? If you see what I see, what is causing the weird clipping into the spheres?

Comment: @JacobPox `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` should cover your bases pretty well.

Comment: you'd need to check the manual for your compiler to find out how to enable full warnings.     The "clipping" is because you're failing to clamp your output colours to the range [0, 255].   If you set the light intensity to 1.0 it looks "right"

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ah, yes, `-Wextra` was the one I was struggling to remember with gcc.   I actually used `clang++` to bring out the uninitialised variables because C++ is stricter about them.

Comment: @Alnitak Is there a standard way of clamping down the outputs? Something like (value % 255) should keep it within the bounds, right?

Comment: @JacobPox `value % 255` would just force it to wrap around.  I think you'd just want to make sure if it goes above 255 or overflows, you instead set it equal to 255.

Comment: @JacobPox you code effectively already does that, because you're writing them into an unsigned char.    You actually need to do the calculations using a large "type", and then ensure that you don't exceed 255 *before* you write any value into an `unsigned char`.

Comment: NB: just clamping the values will result in unattractive "saturation" of your output.   A more pleasing (but harder to implement) result would be to render the entire image into an array of floating point colors, and then scale the output by the brightest pixel found.

Comment: @Alnitak Technically `unsigned char` doesn't have to be 8 bits.  Also, I think overflow should be detectable without using a larger type (is the result smaller than both operands of multiplication?  overflow).

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yeah, I know, it doesn't _have_ to be 8 bits, but it almost always is (and the code makes that assumption anyway) and I think that's a complication too far just now for the OP.    Also, in the code one operand is actually a float and the other is already in the range 0..255, so in fact overflow only happens when that float > 1.0

Comment: @Alnitak Does this mean any light intensity in my program greater than 1 can cause the opposite effect of making something look darker?

Comment: not as such - as written now, if you used a light intensity of 2 (for example)  then your colours would "peak" twice between the points that are supposed to be darkest and brightest.

Comment: (the weird yellow -> green effect you currently see on the occluded sphere is because your red and green components when multiplied by the diffuse lighting component exceed the 255 limit and wrap around to zero on different parts of the sphere)

Comment: @Alnitak I believe I've fixed the issue by having colorArr[0] = ((m.diffuse_color[0] * diffuse_light_intensity > 255) ? (m.diffuse_color[0] * diffuse_light_intensity > 255) : (255)); to each so if the light it larger than 255 it'll just put it to max brightness.

Comment: @JacobPox that works, but a better fix is to simply limit `diffuse_light_intensity` to 1.0.    That avoids repeating the multiplication twice over.